# Find the region for double integrals

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

I have the integral $I = \iint_D\frac 1 {\sqrt x} \, dx \, dy$, where $D: y^2 \leq 8x, y\leq 2x, y+4x\leq 24$. I don't know how to find the bounds for this regions. In general what is the way to find these bounds?

Comment: Did you draw a picture?

Comment: I tryied but I could not. I don't know exactly what functions should I graph. I graphed y = 2x only

Comment: I'd suggest graphing the others too. Look for points of intersection, and try to determine which bounded region in your diagram satisfies all three inequalities.

Comment: https://ibb.co/mpBXOm these are the graphs plotted. So it means that triangle is my D?

Comment: $y^2 = 8x$ isn't a line.

Comment: on that graph I plotted 8x. Should I graph $\sqrt{8x}$

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, to find the boundaries of y, find the lowest function as a lower bound and the largest is an upper bound. As for x, the leftmost function is the lower bound and the rightmost one is the upper bound.

Answer (score 1):

Your region looks something like this.
[image]

You will need to break this region up to integrate it.